# How to get user details who created a perticular job in jenkins through API

Tags: xml, api, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to get all the jobs name and and thier creator from jenkins instance.

I am having a multilevel job config in my instance like:

```
 "Jenkins Dashboard jobs "---> "Folder1 jobs"---->"Folder2 jobs"......"folder6 jobs"
```

currently I am able to print all the jobs name with all level (from dashboard to folder level6)

by this command:

```
https://jenkins_url/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,jobs[name,jobs[name,jobs[name,jobs[name,jobs[name]]]]]]
```

Problem:

How to print job creator name also in the api query.
through api only.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the Job Config History plugin which saves a copy of the configuration file of a job (config.xml) for every change made and of the system configuration (not activated by default). You can search for the Created operation and get the user who created the job.

You can use the following command to get it through the api

```
https://jenkins_url/job/job_name/jobConfigHistory/api/json
```

This will list all the jobs and the operations performed on it. You can search for `<operation>Created</operation>` and list the creator.